# Python e Asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, assincronismo

Estou lendo a documentação da biblioteca asyncio do Python e estou me encontrando em dificuldade para diferenciar alguns termos que são frequentemente usados, são eles: Task, Future.
Ambos os termos são usados de formas similares dái a minha dúvida qual a diferença entre os dois ???